# Where can I find SDK Tools, Revision 6?

Tags: android

Revision 7 broke my build. I need SDK tools revision 6 for Mac OS.

Revision 6 is listed here, http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html
But, I didn't find anywhere to download it. Anyone know?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try to fix you project and make it build with the new version. But if you insist on using the older version [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r06-windows.zip) it is.

You can't find it using their website, but you can always replace 7 with 6 and hope that the file is still there :)

Comment: Sorry but it seems that only the windows version is accessible in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using eclipse and also just updated to SDK tools revision 7. In a quick test, everything worked as expected. Maybe you should try and uninstall/reinstall the SDK tools? Or maybe you could give more information on what exactly broke with revision 7 so that the problem can be solved this way?